# How can I extend mongoose typings to include a cache for cachegoose?

Tags: typescript

I would like to use cachegoose https://www.npmjs.com/package/cachegoose with mongoose but I have to use TypeScript. If I just want to add the .cache option so I can use the below how would I do that?

I dont want to replace the mongoose index.d.ts and I don't have time/knowledge to make a typing's file for cachegoose, I simply want to add the functionality as easily as possible. Something like a Global.d.ts where I can extended mongoose and add cache: any. (Similar to how you can extend the pallet for Material UI)

```
Record
  .find({ some_condition: true })
  .cache(30) // The number of seconds to cache the query.  Defaults to 60 seconds.
  .exec(function(err, records) {
    ...
  });
```